# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.compat.v2.__internal__' has no attribute 'tf2'

Tags: tensorflow2.0

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNEs8.jpg)

Above is the image:
The error is this:

```
LOCAL.GENERATED_WITH_V2 = tf.__internal__.tf2.enabled()
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.compat.v2.__internal__' has no attribute 'tf2'
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you get the solution?

Answer (score 1):

From `Tensorflow 2.x` onward, `keras` is no longer maintained and it became a part of `Tensorflow`. I would recommend instead of `import keras`, you should try `from tensorflow import keras` or `import tensorflow as tf` and use `tf.keras`.

You can import `Sequential` module from `tensorflow` as shown below

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tf.keras import Sequential
```

For more information you can refer [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/49172) and [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Sequential)