# Attribute Error: module 'no tf2 attribute' (Running TF1 code with TF2 with all compatibility)

Tags: python, tensorflow

```
tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()
tf.disable_v2_behavior()
from keras.models import Sequential 
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation
```

This is the code block where I am encountering such an issue:

```
import keras
from keras.datasets import cifar10
from keras.models import Sequential, Model
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, GlobalAveragePooling2D
from keras.applications.resnet50 import ResNet50
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
keras.__version__
```

The output is:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
"ipython-input-3-005a85517711" in "module" <br/>

    ----> 1 import keras
          2 from keras.datasets import cifar10
          3 from keras.models import Sequential, Model
          4 from keras.optimizers import Adam
          5 from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten

~\.conda\envs\weapon\lib\site-packages\keras\__init__.py in "module" <br/>

         18 from . import callbacks
         19 from . import constraints
    ---> 20 from . import initializers
         21 from . import metrics
         22 from . import models

~\.conda\envs\weapon\lib\site-packages\keras\initializers\__init__.py in "module" <br/>

        122 # from ALL_OBJECTS. We make no guarantees as to whether these objects will
        123 # using their correct version.
    --> 124 populate_deserializable_objects()
        125 globals().update(LOCAL.ALL_OBJECTS)
        126 

~\.conda\envs\weapon\lib\site-packages\keras\initializers\__init__.py in populate_deserializable_objects() <br/>

         47 
         48   LOCAL.ALL_OBJECTS = {}
    ---> 49   LOCAL.GENERATED_WITH_V2 = tf.__internal__.tf2.enabled()
         50 
         51   # Compatibility aliases (need to exist in both V1 and V2).

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.compat.v2.__internal__' has no attribute 'tf2'
```

Comment: Can you please avoid sharing text as an image? It would be appreciated if you could replace that image with the actual text of the error message. Thank you.

Comment: @Lescurel I've converted it to code, earlier it wasn't letting me use code blocks and in desperation and frustration I'd upload a image. Please help me out here

Comment: Can you add your version of tensorflow and keras? (`tf.disable_v2_behavior()` hints towards tf 1.15)

Comment: @Lescurel Yes I did that, apparently every time I want to import a module, I have to remind the code to disable v2 behavior, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From comments

> Issue has been resolved by adding `tf.disable_v2_behavior()` at the
> begining (paraphrased from Lescurel)

I would recommend one more solution, instead of `import keras`, you should try `from tensorflow import keras` or `import tensorflow as tf` and use `tf.keras` as shown below

```
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import cifar10
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential, Model
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, GlobalAveragePooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.applications.resnet50 import ResNet50
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
```

For more information you can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67787883/14290681) solution.